# nodejs typescript PostgreSQL bulk insert from an array to a table using COPY

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, bulkinsert

My array would have close to 500k rows. After desearlising the data, my array in nodejs looks like this

```
const bulkData = [
    [1234, 'abs@xyz.com', 'tokyo'],
    [2345, 'abs@xyz.com', 'london'],
    [1243, 'abs@xyz.com', 'paris'],
    ...
    ...
]
```

Rest of the variables are:

```
const tableName = 'my_test_table'
const columnNamesString = 'user_id, email, city'
// there are other columns in the table that will have default values so i don't need to insert data into all columns. only the above 3
```

My code for `COPY` is not working. I am getting a `Connection: Terminated` error but the error does not contain any other information. Here's the full error

```
Error: Connection terminated
    at Connection.<anonymous> (D:\repos\hfscripts\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:132:36)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:28)
    at Connection.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Connection.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\repos\hfscripts\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:63:12)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at Socket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (node:net:313:12)
```

My code is:

```
import { Client } from 'pg';
import { from as copyFrom } from 'pg-copy-streams';
const pgClient = new Client(config);
// connection works. i have tested it. 'config' contains key-value paris needed for connection

const queryText = `COPY ${tableName}(${columnNameString}) FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','`;
console.log(queryText)
const stream = pgClient.query(copyFrom(queryText));

stream.on('finish', () => {
  console.log('Bulk insert completed');
});

stream.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(
    `ERROR during Bulk insert`
  );
  throw err;
});

bulkData.forEach((rowData) => {
  const csvRow = `${rowData.join(',')}`;
  console.log(csvRow);
  stream.write(csvRow);
});
```

When i do `console.log()` for the query and the data, i get this

`COPY my_test_table(user_id,email,city) FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ','`
`1234,'abs@xyz.com','tokyo'`

any idea how to fix this? The alternative i have is to copy the entire array into a .csv and then create a readStream and insert the data. But that seems like an overhead

Comment: Assuming you are using [pg-copy-streams](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-copy-streams) I don't see where you are setting up `fileStream.pipe(stream)` as shown in COPY FROM example at link.

Comment: Hi Adrian, i am using pg-copy-streams, yes. I didn't understand the comment. the `fileStream.pip(stream)` would be for a "file". right? in my case, it is an array that i need to insert into the table

Comment: Go to the link posted above and then the section *pipe from a file to table (copyIn - copy-from)*. From what I see in the code you need to provide both a stream to the database table as in `const stream = pgClient.query(copyFrom(queryText));`  and a stream from the file which in the example is `var fileStream = fs.createReadStream('some_file.tsv')` using `var fs = require('node:fs')`. You then connect them using `fileStream.pip(stream)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @adrian-klaver for the solution. I needed to stream the string too.

Here's what I did:

1. Convert my bulkData into a csvString, say `bulkDataCsvString`
2. Create a readble stream for this string

```
import { Readable } from 'node:stream';

const src = new Readable();
src.readable = true;
src.push(bulkDataCsvString);
src.push(null);

src.pipe(stream) // stream is the name of the PostgreSQL query

// rest of the code as is. BUT remove the forEach code. its not needed
```